# Mute Stanford coreNLP logging

Tags: java, logging, slf4j, stanford-nlp

First of all, Java is not my usual language, so I'm quite basic at it. I need to use it for this particular project, so please be patient, and if I have omitted any relevant information, please ask for it, I will be happy to provide it.

I have been able to implement coreNLP, and, seemingly, have it working right, but is generating lots of messages like:

```
ene 20, 2017 10:38:42 AM edu.stanford.nlp.process.PTBLexer next
ADVERTENCIA: Untokenizable: 【 (U+3010, decimal: 12304)
```

After some research (documentation, google, other threads here), I *think* (sorry, I don't know how I can tell for sure) coreNLP is finding the `slf4j-api.jar` in my classpath, and logging through it.

Which properties of the JVM can I use to set logging level of the messages that will be printed out?

Also, in which `.properties` file I could set them? (I already have a `commons-logging.properties`, a `simplelog.properties` and a `StanfordCoreNLP.properties` in my project's resource folder to set properties for other packages).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Om’s answer is good, but two other possibly useful approaches:

- If it is just these warnings from the tokenizer that are annoying you, you can (in code or in StanfordCoreNLP.properties) set a property so they disappear: `props.setProperty("tokenize.options", "untokenizable=NoneKeep");`.
- If slf4j is on the classpath, then, by default, our own Redwoods logger will indeed log through slf4j. So, you can also set the logging level using slf4j.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem, you want to disable all StanfordNLP logging message while the program is executing.

You can disable the logging message. `Redwood` logging framework is used as logging framework in Stanford NLP. First, clear the `Redwood`'s default configuration(to display log message) then create StanfordNLP pipeline.

```
import edu.stanford.nlp.util.logging.RedwoodConfiguration;
RedwoodConfiguration.current().clear().apply();
StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

In accordance with Christopher Manning's suggestion, I followed this link
[How to configure slf4j-simple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14544991/how-to-configure-slf4j-simple)

I created a file `src/simplelogger.properties` with the line `org.slf4j.simpleLogger.defaultLogLevel=warn`.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to solve it by setting a blank output stream to system error stream.

```
System.setErr(new PrintStream(new BlankOutputStream())); // set blank error stream
// ... Add annotators ...
System.setErr(System.err); // Reset to default
```

Accompanying class is

```
public class BlankOutputStream extends OutputStream {

    @Override
    public void write(int b) throws IOException {
        // Do nothing
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Om's answer disables all logging. However, if you wish to still log errors then use:

```
RedwoodConfiguration.errorLevel().apply();
```

I also use jdk logging instead of slf4j logging to avoid loading slfj dependencies as follows:

```
RedwoodConfiguration.javaUtilLogging().apply();
```

Both options can be used together and in any order. Required import is:

```
import edu.stanford.nlp.util.logging.RedwoodConfiguration;
```